# Vala How to output an array without loops?

Tags: console, output, vala

I have a function that returns an array int.

```
int[] someFunc(int a){
int[] b = new int[a];
return b;
}
```

I want to output the result of this function to the console in one line without changing this function.

In C# I can do it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine (string.Join("\n", someFunc(3)));
```

but Vala doesn't have a join function that takes int[]
So again, the question is: how to output an array to the console without loops and without changing the function?

Comment: What is wrong with loops? You could easily write such a function yourself with loops.

Comment: Take a look at Microsofts code here: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L92

Comment: the first title of the question was "in one line", I just want to find a way to make it nice and fast.

Comment: Using join is unlikely to be particularly fast.  It's using a loop internally, dynamically allocating an array and resizing it as necessary.  Much faster to just use your own loop and avoid the intermediary string.